# pfu Turbo DNA polymerase AD

Tags: pcr

What is the duration (Life") of pfu turbo DNA polymerase AD. I am trying o Amplification a 3.3kb fragment and the PCR schedule is 6 hours long. The manufacturers notes just specify that its activity remains 94-99% in 1 hour at 95, nothing more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the exact half-life of this special Pfu polymerase, but generally Pfu polymerases are pretty stable. This [source](http://www.biocompare.com/Application-Notes/41999-Pfu-DNA-Polymerase-As-A-Hot-Start-Alternative/) gives a half life of 18-25 hours at 95°C, meaning you keep the enzyme at 95°C for the whole time a you still have 50% activity after that time. Since you don't do that, I wouldn't worry too much about the activity. To be safe, you can add an extra long (probably 10-15 minutes) single amplification step before cooling down.